# A question about "getTimeDay" in functions -comparisons-conditions

Tags: javascript, if-statement, comparison

sorry to ask the simple question in this advanced platform full of great coders, please point out what i have to correct my code.Thank you so much!

**1.here is the code requirements:**

Declare a function getTimeOfDay. For reference:

4:00 AM (inclusive) - 12:00 PM (exclusive): morning

12:00 PM (inclusive) - 5:00 PM (exclusive): afternoon

5:00 PM (inclusive) - 8:30 PM (exclusive): evening

8:30 PM (inclusive) - 4:00 AM (exclusive): night

/**

- @param {1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12} ??? - the hour (12-hour style)
- @param {number} ??? - the number of minutes past the hour
- @param {'AM'|'PM'} ??? - "AM" or "PM"
- @returns {'morning'|'afternoon'|'evening'|'night'} the rough "time of day"

*/

**2.here is the TEST that i am supposed to pass:**

actual = getTimeOfDay(4, 0, "AM");

expected = "morning";

if (actual === expected) {

console.log("Yay! Test PASSED.");

} else {

console.error("Test FAILED. Keep trying!");

console.log("    actual: ", actual);

console.log("  expected: ", expected);
}

actual = getTimeOfDay(3, 59, "AM");

expected = "night";

if (actual === expected) {

console.log("Yay! Test PASSED.");

} else {

console.error("Test FAILED. Keep trying!");

console.log("    actual: ", actual);

console.log("  expected: ", expected);

}

**3.here is my code:**

```
    function getTimeOfDay(hr,num,AM){

      if(hr === AM){

        if(hr >= 4 && hr < 12){

         if(num >=0 && num <= 59){

           return "morning";
       }
       }
     }

     else if(hr >= 12 && hr < 5)

          return "afternoon";

     else if(hr >=5 && hr < 8){

     if(num >=0 && num <= 30)

        return "evening";

    else

        return "night";

   }
 }
```

**4.here is the error message from my code:**

[image]

Comment: What is the meaning of that condition `if(hr === AM)`? and please edit the question to be formatted properly

Comment: if I understand this question properly, you are expected to create a function to decipher the time of the depending on the argument provided to the function? then why are you adding "AM" as an argument?

Comment: @MernaMustafa Sorry for the format. Because there are three parameters, which the are "hour" ,"minute" and AM(or PM), i don't how to make the logic clear and then return four different times of the day, such as "morning",etc,.

Comment: @JerryJoseph Definitely "AM" is one of the parameters here in the task.

Answer (score 1):

The main cause of the error is that condition `if(hr === AM)`, I have modified the code a little bit.

```js
function getTimeOfDay(hr,num,period){

      if(period == "AM" ){

        if(hr >= 4 && hr < 12){

         if(num >=0 && num <= 59){

           return "morning";
         }
       }
       else{
        return "night";
       }
     }

     else{

     if(hr >= 12 && hr < 5)

          return "afternoon";

     else if(hr >=5 && hr < 8){

     if(num >=0 && num <= 30)

        return "evening";

    else

        return "night";

   }
}
 }
```

Note: conditions maybe could be written in a better way, I didn't check their correctness but the provided test cases are passed, I just wanted to highlight the cause of error for you.

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you please kindly explain that what does if(AM == "AM")mean?

Comment: Your third parameter is a string which is "AM" or "PM", so you can call this parameter a `period` as a better name (I have updated the answer with this point). then you could check if `period == "AM"` or `period == "PM"` and proceed with the rest conditions.